# bind method needed or not?

Tags: javascript, bind

Is there a difference between the two assignments below regarding the bind method? And when is bind necessary, because they do seem to work without bind as well.

option 1

```
var xxxRequestAnimFrame = foo();

function foo() {
    var rAF =
    window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

//  if (rAF === undefined) {return undefined;} else {return rAF.bind(window);}
    if (rAF === undefined) {return undefined;} else {return rAF;}
}
```

option 2

```
var xxxRequestAnimFrame = (function() {
    var rAF =
    window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

//  if (rAF === undefined) {return undefined} else {return rAF.bind(window);}
    if (rAF === undefined) {return undefined} else {return rAF;}
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that one creates the `foo` variable in the enclosing scope. If you're never going to call the function again, it's pointless.

However, you don't need a function at all

```
var xxxRequestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame   ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame;
```

No need for `.bind()` either unless there's something special you're trying to accomplish.

---

In particular, this line was needlessly verbose:

```
if (rAF === undefined) {return undefined} else {return rAF;}
```

It's equivalent to:

```
return rAF;
```

---

If for some reason you did want to bind `window` (though I'm not sure why that would be), I'd do this:

```
var xxxRequestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame   ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

xxxRequestAnimFrame = xxxRequestAnimFrame && xxxRequestAnimFrame.bind(window);
```

---

Or if you wanted a no-op function when none is found, and you also wanted to `.bind()`, I'd do this:

```
var xxxRequestAnimFrame = (window.requestAnimationFrame   ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || function(){}).bind(window);
```

Comment: I can not test it, but I think the problem was IE9. In any case, I don't need bind for IE11, Chrome, Opera, Safari and FF.

Comment: Fwiw, PhantomJS and old Safari do not have bind.

Comment: @MaëlNison: Nor does old IE (8 and lower), but it can be patched if desired.